# DD-WRT setup access restrictions but allow VPN connections freely

Tags: iptables, router, site-to-site-vpn

I have two sites with DD-WRT connected via routed VPN. Clients on both routers have Internet Access Restrictions set. This works and correctly blocks internet access. But this also blocks connection between client PCs of the two sites. How do i configure the access restrictions to allow/whitelist connections passing through VPN?